# Exclude Child Posts from WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, children

How can I exclude child posts using wp_query? Given the following architecture:

- parent 1

  - child 1
  - child 2
- parent 2

  - child 3
  - child 4

I'd like to only return parent 1 and parent 2, and exclude child 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I've searched high and low for an answer to this question. Nothing surfaces.

Comment: posts don't usually have a hierachy - do you mean pages?

Comment: posts do have hierarchical capabilities.

Comment: @LeePeterson Yap it's true. With plugins like `CPT UI` you can create a custom post type and add the page-attribute to it to make them hierarchical.

Answer (score 18):

use `'post_parent' => 0` in WP_Query to return only parent posts

Comment: As soon as I posted my question, I found the answer somewhere else online. Thank you for the correct response!!

Comment: but 'post_parent' only works with pages no?
What about "posts" on categories?

Comment: @eveevans please ask a new question to get specific help for what you are trying to achieve.